# Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource:

Tags: smarty, sugarcrm

I installed new version of sugarCRM, and in some page is show up next warning"

**Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: ....**

I spend a lot of time on web to find solution but with out success, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: can you provide more information ?

Comment: When i go in SugarCRM->Salse->Accounts->[some account] in the last field "Email Address:" extend emails i see message:"Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "include/SugarFields/Fields/Base/detailViewFunction.tpl" in /home/campusre/public_html/sugar/include/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1095"

Comment: check if `include/SugarFields/Fields/Base/detailViewFunction.tpl` exists or readable by SugarCRM .

Comment: the file exists by with capital first latter include/SugarFields/Fields/Base/DetailViewFunction.tpl, i change with the small letter by show the same problem and i return again the Big latter. How can I check does is readable in SugarCRM?

Comment: to find out whether it's permission problem, set the file permission to `777` (its containing folder as well). If the problem vanishes, it's permission problem.

Comment: I still have the same problem :(

Comment: You have set the Smart template directory http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl right?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find what triggered this error for me.  I looked for any odd register_resource calls but didn't find any.  I ended up suppressing the warning.  This is for Smarty 2

```
@@ -1411,7 +1411,7 @@
 {

     $_params = array('resource_name' => $resource_name);
-        if (! $this->_fetch_resource_info($_params)) {
+        if (! @$this->_fetch_resource_info($_params)) {
         return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when i use smarty 2 as template engine. 
I have used xampp as localhost. since i am using windows, i didn't face permission issue for the template directories and directory spelling issues.
But i have also checked permission for folder and it was 777,and other solution provided in https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/troubleshooting.

Finally updating the Smarty library solve my issue.
Download the latest Smarty files and Replace them with your current library.

https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/releases/tag/v2.6.31
unzip ->\smarty-2.6.31\libs copy files from \libs folder and paste it to your smarty Library -> \library\Smarty.

Hope it helps.