# SugarCRM /include/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1095 troubleshoot

Tags: smarty, sugarcrm

I have been searching for this problem since a while but without much help. Everyone seemed to leave it half way.

I want to dig a bit deeper as to why and how it is creating such a havoc for everyone.

**Environment**
Installed SugarCRM and installed addon module. The module seems to work however, around email line it shoots a warning on the page:

```
Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "include/SugarFields/FieldsBase/detailViewFunction.tpl" in /public_html/xxx/include/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1095
```

As per the suggestions earlier from other post, I have done following and I am still at square 1

- Changed the filename to all possible combinations
- Searched for code where it references detailViewFunction. It appears in base and enum folder only and is exactly same the way the filename is. There is no mention in the code OR file about small d as suggested by someone one of the users in StackOverflow. Simply put, it is not detailViewFunction; in both files it appears as DetailViewFunction and the filename is same as this.
- Checked permissions and they are 755; tried changing to 777 but still the error is there.

Any one who was able to solve it?

El

Ref.: [Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933007/warning-smarty-error-unable-to-read-resource)

Comment: Does the file actually exist?`include/SugarFields/FieldsBase/detailViewFunction.tpl`. if `detaiViewFunction.tpl` is not in the fieldBase directory, it will give you that warning message.

Comment: Find out what the exact defined template directory is. It might be including the wrong path.